# how to transfer field value from project to project mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework, field, aggregation

I need to count sum of needed (cond) values in MongoDB. I am using pipeline aggregation. How can i transfer(pass) **currentScore** through all documents?

```
{
      $group: {
       _id: { name: '$_id' },
       currentScore: { $sum: 0 },
      },
   },
   {
      $project: {
        _id: '$_id',
        currentScore: {
          $cond: {
            if: { '$boolean' },
            then: { $sum: ['$currentScore', 1] },
            else: 0,
          },
        },
      },
    },
```

Something like this... But in that case i got only 1 or 0.... Even if my cond is true for several documents in a row.

Comment: What are you expecting in output? Multiple documents or a single document with the currentScore only?

Comment: if you  put `currentScore:1`, it will be included

Comment: `{ $sum: 0 }` will always be `0`, what were you intending for that to do?